# How to fix php5-mcrypt on Ubuntu 13.10 install via puppet?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, php-mcrypt

I'm pretty new to Puppet. So, I'm here asking for help on how the best way to fix my problem.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lucasvscn/puppet-php) puppet module to provision PHP into my Ubuntu 13.10 box. But, it seems that package `php5-mcrypt` is broken since, `mcrypt.ini` is misplaced at `/etc/php5/conf.d` instead of `/etc/php5/apache2/available-modules/`

(For the record, I'm working with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5)

I've made a class `php-mcrypt` that 'works for me'. But, I want to know if there's a better/cleaner way to do it.

Here's my workaround:

```
# https://github.com/lucasvscn/puppet-php-mcrypt
#
class php-mcrypt() {


  Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

  package { "php5-mcrypt":
    ensure  => "installed",
    require => Class['php'],
  }

  file { '/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini':
    require => Package['php5-mcrypt'],
  }

  exec {
    "copying_mcrypt":
    command => 'cp -v /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/',
    require => Package['php5-mcrypt'],
  }->

  exec {
    "enabling_mcrypt":
    command => 'php5enmod mcrypt && service apache2 reload',
    require => Package['php5-mcrypt'],
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the package itself was discussed in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10) and this Ubuntu bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1241286).

The commonly accepted resolution is to create a symlink as opposed to copying the file. That method has the advantage of having your configuration point to a file that is still under the package management system's control.

Here is a Puppet example: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/creating-a-symlink.html

Comment: What I really wanted was a better solution to my approach using Puppet. but, thanks buddy.. I'm going to change from `cp` to `ln` ;)

Comment: @lucasvscn I added a link to a Puppet example.

Answer (score 0):

Manage the link as a Puppet File resource type instead of the more convoluted Exec of ln. Ensure => link and specify target => param.

Comment: Would you please provide some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Enable php5-mcrypt with puppet in Ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04

```
case $lsbdistid {
    'Ubuntu': {

        case $lsbdistrelease {
            '13.10': {
                file { '/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini':
                    ensure => link,
                    target => '/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini',
                    notify => Service['apache2'],
                    require => [
                        Package['libapache2-mod-php5'],
                        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
                    ],
                }
                file { '/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini':
                    ensure => link,
                    target => '/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini',
                    require => [
                        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
                        Package['php5-cli'],
                    ],
                }
            }

            '14.04': {
                file { '/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini':
                    ensure => link,
                    target => '../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini',
                    notify => Service['apache2'],
                    require => [
                        Package['libapache2-mod-php5'],
                        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
                    ],
                }
                file { '/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini':
                    ensure => link,
                    target => '../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini',
                    require => [
                        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
                        Package['php5-cli'],
                    ],
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```